Use Cellular Data while Maintaining Connection to Offline Wifi Hotspot
For a project I'm doing, I want to maintain a connection to an offline wifi hotspot.  I want to do this so I can interact with the device wirelessly.
I want to also, at the same time, be able to use my phone to browse the internet.
So
Device A : 100% offline.  Wifi Hotspot Emitting.
Device B : Phone.  Connected to Wifi Hotspot.  Use Cellular Data for internet.
Is this possible?  I have the newest iPhone with the newest iOS if it helps. I have Wifi Assist turned on in Cellular Settings, but it seems that just puts you on Cellular when the Wifi internet is poor (thus killing my connection to Device A).

Sorry, home networking, consumer-grade hardware and host configurations/issues are explicitly off topic here, see the [help/on-topic]. You might want to try on [su].

iPhones will connect to wifi that doesn't lead to the internet. Make sure that wifi doesn't claim to be the default gateway.
